Chess AI: Easy endgames and transposition tables
I have 2 problems with my chess engine I can't seem to figure out/understand. The first is with easy endgames. I was using this video as a reference (18:30 for the easy endgames), and implemented the same code he did, but adapted to how I designed the engine. Instead of always maximizing the score for both sides, I want to take the maximum score for white and the minimum for black.
Code for my endgame evaluation:
def endGameEval(self, endgameWeight: float, isWhite: bool) -> int:
        """
        endGameEval gives a higher score to moves that force the enemy 
        king to the backRanks when the game is closer to the end.
        """
        eval = 0
        blackKingSquare = ch.square_name(self.pythonBoard.king(ch.BLACK))
        blackKingRank = int(blackKingSquare[1])
        blackKingFile = ord(blackKingSquare[0]) - ord('a') + 1

        whiteKingSquare = ch.square_name(self.pythonBoard.king(ch.WHITE))
        whiteKingRank = int(whiteKingSquare[1])
        whiteKingFile = ord(whiteKingSquare[0]) - ord('a') + 1
        if (isWhite == False):
            EnemyDistToCentreFile = max(3 - whiteKingFile, whiteKingFile - 4)
            EnemyDistToCentreRank = max(3 - whiteKingRank, whiteKingRank - 4)
            EnemyDistFromCentre = EnemyDistToCentreFile + EnemyDistToCentreRank
        else:
            EnemyDistToCentreFile = max(3 - blackKingFile, blackKingFile - 4)
            EnemyDistToCentreRank = max(3 - blackKingRank, blackKingRank - 4)
            EnemyDistFromCentre = EnemyDistToCentreFile + EnemyDistToCentreRank
        eval += EnemyDistFromCentre

        fileDist = abs(blackKingFile - whiteKingFile)
        rankDist = abs(blackKingRank - whiteKingRank)
        kingDist = fileDist + rankDist
        eval += 14 - kingDist
        # if (isWhite == False):
        #     eval = -eval
        return int(eval * endgameWeight)

I commented
if (isWhite == False):
       eval = -eval

out because the engine was making random moves in some endgame positions like this one.
I tried switching up the values to extremes for this part:
fileDist = abs(blackKingFile - whiteKingFile)
        rankDist = abs(blackKingRank - whiteKingRank)
        kingDist = fileDist + rankDist
        eval += 14 - kingDist

but nothing changed.
Here's my engine class,
class Engine():
    """
    Class that controls the engine with the moves
    """
    def __init__(self, board: dict[str: str], pythonBoard: ch.Board, whitePieces: int, blackPieces: int, transpositions: defaultdict) -> None:
        self.board = board
        self.pythonBoard = pythonBoard
        self.materialValue = 0
        self.move = None
        self.transpositions = transpositions
        self.whitePieces = whitePieces
        self.blackPieces = blackPieces


    def attackedByPawn(self, start: str, color: str) -> bool:
        """
        attackedByPawn detects if a piece at position start with the color color is attacked by a pawn.
        A pinned pawn will count as an attacker.
        """
        if (color == "white"):
            left = ""
            right = ""
            # check row
            if (start[1] != '8'):
                # check column
                if (start[0] != 'a'):
                    left = chr(ord(start[0]) - 1) + str(int(start[1]) + 1)
                    if (self.board[left] == 'p' and self.pythonBoard.is_pinned(ch.BLACK, ch.parse_square(left)) == False):
                        return True
                if (start[0] != 'h'):
                    right = chr(ord(start[0]) + 1) + str(int(start[1]) + 1)
                    if (self.board[right] == 'p' and self.pythonBoard.is_pinned(ch.BLACK, ch.parse_square(right)) == False):
                        return True
                return False
        else:
            left = ""
            right = ""
            # check row
            if (start[1] != '1'):
                # check column
                if (start[0] != 'a'):
                    right = chr(ord(start[0]) - 1) + str(int(start[1]) - 1)
                    if (self.board[right] == 'P' and self.pythonBoard.is_pinned(ch.WHITE, ch.parse_square(right)) == False):
                        return True
                if (start[0] != 'h'):
                    left = chr(ord(start[0]) + 1) + str(int(start[1]) - 1)
                    if (self.board[left] == 'P' and self.pythonBoard.is_pinned(ch.WHITE, ch.parse_square(left)) == False):
                        return True
                return False

    def orderMoves(self, moves: set[str], start: str) -> list[str]:
        """
        orderMoves sorts the moves in an order with estimates to how good the
        move is. There are 4 criterias: 
        Move to capture a piece, 
        Move to promote,
        Move that gets a piece attacked by a pawn
        Checkmate
        """
        valList = []
        moveName = self.board[start]
        moveColor = findColor(moveName)
        movePiece = Piece(moveName, moveColor, 0, set())
        for move in moves:
            move = move[:2]
            targetName = self.board[move]
            # if there's a piece on the square, check the captured piece
            if (targetName != '0'):
                targetColor = findColor(targetName)
                targetPiece = Piece(targetName, targetColor, 0, set())
                val = abs(targetPiece.value)
                val = 10 * val - abs(movePiece.value)
            else:
                val = 0
            self.pythonBoard.push(ch.Move.from_uci(start + move))
            if (self.pythonBoard.is_checkmate):
                val += 10000000
            self.pythonBoard.pop()
            # check for promotion
            if ((move[1] == '8' and moveName == 'P') or (move[1] == '1' or moveName == 'p')):
                val += 9
            # check for pawn attacks
            if (self.attackedByPawn(move, moveColor)):
                val -= movePiece.value
            valList.append(val)
        moves = list(moves)
        combined = list(zip(moves, valList))
        return [move[0] for move in sorted(combined, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)]

    def endGameEval(self, endgameWeight: float, isWhite: bool) -> int:
        """
        endGameEval gives a higher score to moves that force the enemy 
        king to the backRanks when the game is closer to the end.
        """
        eval = 0
        blackKingSquare = ch.square_name(self.pythonBoard.king(ch.BLACK))
        blackKingRank = int(blackKingSquare[1])
        blackKingFile = ord(blackKingSquare[0]) - ord('a') + 1

        whiteKingSquare = ch.square_name(self.pythonBoard.king(ch.WHITE))
        whiteKingRank = int(whiteKingSquare[1])
        whiteKingFile = ord(whiteKingSquare[0]) - ord('a') + 1
        if (isWhite == False):
            EnemyDistToCentreFile = max(3 - whiteKingFile, whiteKingFile - 4)
            EnemyDistToCentreRank = max(3 - whiteKingRank, whiteKingRank - 4)
            EnemyDistFromCentre = EnemyDistToCentreFile + EnemyDistToCentreRank
        else:
            EnemyDistToCentreFile = max(3 - blackKingFile, blackKingFile - 4)
            EnemyDistToCentreRank = max(3 - blackKingRank, blackKingRank - 4)
            EnemyDistFromCentre = EnemyDistToCentreFile + EnemyDistToCentreRank
        eval += EnemyDistFromCentre

        fileDist = abs(blackKingFile - whiteKingFile)
        rankDist = abs(blackKingRank - whiteKingRank)
        kingDist = fileDist + rankDist
        eval += 14 - kingDist
        # if (isWhite == False):
        #     eval = -eval
        return int(eval * endgameWeight)

    def evaluate(self, isWhite: bool) -> float:
        """
        evaluate evaluates the position
        """
        materialValue = 0
        squares = list(self.board.keys())
        if (self.pythonBoard.is_stalemate()):
            return 0
        if (self.pythonBoard.outcome() != None):
            if (self.pythonBoard.outcome().winner == True):
                    return float('inf')
            elif (self.pythonBoard.outcome().winner == False):
                return float('-inf')
        for square in squares:
            # if there's a piece on the square
            if (self.board[square] != '0'):
                name = self.board[square]
                if (name.islower()):
                    color = "black"
                else:
                    color = "white"
                moves = set()
                piece = Piece(name, color, 0, moves)
                materialValue += piece.value * 10
        if (isWhite):
            endGameBonus = self.endGameEval(16 - self.whitePieces, isWhite)
        else:
            endGameBonus = self.endGameEval(16 - self.blackPieces, isWhite)
        return materialValue + endGameBonus

    def isCapture(self, square: str) -> bool:
        if (self.board[square] != '0'):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def findCaptureMoves(self, allMoves: list[ch.Move], currPos: str) -> set[str]:
        """
        Finds all capture moves of the piece at currPos which is a string representing 
        a square on the board, such as a8 using allMoves which is a list containing 
        every legal move of every piece
        """
        legalMoves = set()
        for location in allMoves:
            pos = str(location)[2:4]
            try:
                # add move if it's legal
                if (ch.Move.from_uci(currPos + pos) in allMoves and self.board[pos] != '0'):
                    legalMoves.add(pos)
            except ch.InvalidMoveError:
                pass
        return legalMoves

    def searchCaptures(self, whiteTurn: bool, alpha: int, beta: int) -> float:
        """
        Search captures looks at sequences of immediate captures to ensure that
        the score given to the position is accurate even after the depth has ran out.
        It inherits alpha and beta from the search function as well as whiteTurn.
        """
        evaluation = self.evaluate(whiteTurn)
        squares = list(self.board.keys())
        possibleMoves = {}
        end = False
        if (whiteTurn):
            bestEvaluation = float('-inf')
            alpha = max(alpha, evaluation)
            if (alpha >= beta):
                return alpha
            for square in squares:
                if (self.board[square] != '0' and self.board[square].isupper()):
                    possibleMoves[square] = self.orderMoves(self.findCaptureMoves(self.pythonBoard.legal_moves, square), square)
            whiteSquares = list(possibleMoves.keys())
            for whiteSquare in whiteSquares:
                for move in possibleMoves[whiteSquare]:
                    self.pythonBoard.push(ch.Move.from_uci(whiteSquare + move))
                    self.board = fenConverter(self.pythonBoard.board_fen())
                    evaluation = self.searchCaptures(not whiteTurn, alpha, beta)
                    if (evaluation > bestEvaluation):
                        bestEvaluation = evaluation
                    self.pythonBoard.pop()
                    self.board = fenConverter(self.pythonBoard.board_fen())
                    alpha = max(alpha, evaluation)
                    if (beta <= alpha):
                        end = True
                        break
                if (end):
                    break
        else:
            bestEvaluation = float('inf')
            beta = min(beta, evaluation)
            if (alpha >= beta):
                return beta
            for square in squares:
                if (self.board[square] != '0' and self.board[square].isupper()):
                    possibleMoves[square] = self.orderMoves(self.findCaptureMoves(self.pythonBoard.legal_moves, square), square)
            blackSquares = list(possibleMoves.keys())
            for blackSquare in blackSquares:
                for move in possibleMoves[blackSquare]:
                    self.pythonBoard.push(ch.Move.from_uci(blackSquare + move))
                    self.board = fenConverter(self.pythonBoard.board_fen())
                    evaluation = self.searchCaptures(not whiteTurn, alpha, beta)
                    if (evaluation < bestEvaluation):
                        bestEvaluation = evaluation
                    self.pythonBoard.pop()
                    self.board = fenConverter(self.pythonBoard.board_fen())
                    beta = min(beta, evaluation)
                    if (beta <= alpha):
                        end = True
                        break
                if (end):
                    break
        return evaluation


    def search(self, depth: int, whiteTurn: bool, alpha: int, beta: int) -> float:
        """
        search function will give scores to position after searching with a
        depth of depth.
        """
        possibleMoves = {}
        end = False
        squares = list(self.board.keys())
        # end of depth
        if (depth == 0):
            return self.searchCaptures(whiteTurn, alpha, beta)
        # trying to maximize the score
        if (whiteTurn):
            for square in squares:
                if (self.board[square] != '0' and self.board[square].isupper()):
                    possibleMoves[square] = self.orderMoves(findLegalMoves(self.pythonBoard.legal_moves, square), square)
            bestEvaluation = float('-inf')
            whiteSquares = list(possibleMoves.keys())
            # go through all possible moves of each white piece
            for whiteSquare in whiteSquares:
                for move in possibleMoves[whiteSquare]:
                    self.pythonBoard.push(ch.Move.from_uci(whiteSquare + move))
                    fenBoard = self.pythonBoard.board_fen()
                    self.board = fenConverter(fenBoard)

                    if (self.transpositions[(fenBoard, whiteTurn)][0] != None and self.transpositions[(fenBoard, whiteTurn)][1] > depth):
                        evaluation = self.transpositions[(fenBoard, whiteTurn)][0]
                        if (evaluation > bestEvaluation):
                            bestEvaluation = evaluation
                        self.pythonBoard.pop()
                        self.board = fenConverter(self.pythonBoard.board_fen())
                        alpha = max(alpha, evaluation)
                        if (beta <= alpha):
                            end = True
                            break
                        continue

                    evaluation = self.search(depth - 1, not whiteTurn, alpha, beta) # alpha best for white, beta best for black
                    if (self.transpositions[(fenBoard, whiteTurn)][0] == None):
                        self.transpositions[(fenBoard, whiteTurn)] = [evaluation, depth]
                    if (evaluation > bestEvaluation):
                        bestEvaluation = evaluation
                    self.pythonBoard.pop()
                    self.board = fenConverter(self.pythonBoard.board_fen())
                    alpha = max(alpha, evaluation)
                    # Pruning
                    if (beta <= alpha):
                        end = True
                        break
                if (end):
                    break
            return bestEvaluation
        # trying to minimize the score
        else:
            for square in squares:
                if (self.board[square] != '0' and self.board[square].islower()):
                    possibleMoves[square] = self.orderMoves(findLegalMoves(self.pythonBoard.legal_moves, square), square)
            bestEvaluation = float('inf')
            blackSquares = list(possibleMoves.keys())
            # go through all possible moves of each black piece
            for blackSquare in blackSquares:
                for move in possibleMoves[blackSquare]:
                    self.pythonBoard.push(ch.Move.from_uci(blackSquare + move))
                    fenBoard = self.pythonBoard.board_fen()
                    self.board = fenConverter(fenBoard)
                    if (self.pythonBoard.is_checkmate() and depth == DEPTH):
                        self.move = ch.Move.from_uci(blackSquare + move)
                        self.pythonBoard.pop()
                        return float('-inf')

                    if (self.transpositions[(fenBoard, whiteTurn)][0] != None and self.transpositions[(fenBoard, whiteTurn)][1] > depth):
                        evaluation = self.transpositions[(fenBoard, whiteTurn)][0]
                        if (evaluation < bestEvaluation):
                            bestEvaluation = evaluation
                            if (depth == DEPTH):
                                self.move = ch.Move.from_uci(blackSquare + move)
                                self.materialValue = bestEvaluation

                        self.pythonBoard.pop()
                        self.board = fenConverter(self.pythonBoard.board_fen())
                        beta = min(beta, evaluation)
                        if (beta <= alpha):
                            end = True
                            break
                        continue

                    evaluation = self.search(depth - 1, not whiteTurn, alpha, beta)

                    if (depth == DEPTH):
                        pass
                        # print(self.pythonBoard, '\n', evaluation)

                    if (self.transpositions[(fenBoard, whiteTurn)] == None):
                        self.transpositions[(fenBoard, whiteTurn)] = [evaluation, depth]
                    # if we get better score
                    if (evaluation < bestEvaluation):
                        bestEvaluation = evaluation
                        # Choose the move. Only legal moves for the next turn will be at depth DEPTH
                        if (depth == DEPTH):
                            self.move = ch.Move.from_uci(blackSquare + move)
                            self.materialValue = bestEvaluation
                    self.pythonBoard.pop()
                    self.board = fenConverter(self.pythonBoard.board_fen())
                    beta = min(beta, evaluation)
                    if (beta < alpha):
                        end = True
                        break
                if (end):
                    break
            return bestEvaluation


As for the transposition tables, I have tried to run the engine with and without them at depth 5, but the runtime was basically the same. From my understanding, I just need to store the position, which points to the score of the position and what depth is was found at, and if I can search with a higher depth, I update it.
I'm using the minimax algorithm with alpha beta pruning.
I will gladly add more information if it's needed.

Are you sure that the indentation at the end is how it's supposed to be?

Did this fix it?
